# Does a new kernel contain all patches with all the options

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, kernel, real-time

Well, let's start with what I know.
I know that I can apply a linux kernel patch to upgrade my current kernel version. let's say that I've a 4.2 version and I want to upgrade to 4.3 I can apply this patch:
https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v4.x/patch-4.3.xz

Now let's say that I don't want that I want to install the 4.3 kernel(without patching my current one) I can do that by:
https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v4.x/linux-4.3.tar.xz

Now let's move on to what ruined my knowledge, while researching on how to make a linux kernel run in RealTime, I found that I need to apply this patch to the kernel that I downloaded:
https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/rt/4.1/patch-4.1.15-rt17.patch.xz

My question here is: Does "linux-4.3.tar.xz" have RT support on no, to have it available I need to apply "patch-4.1.15-rt17.patch.xz" to any kernel that I want to be supporting RealTime feature  ?

some Src: http://proaudio.tuxfamily.org/wiki/index.php?title=Realtime_(RT)_Kernel#Obtain_the_kernel-source_and_necessary_patches

Answer (score 2):

New kernel contains only *accepted* patches. AFAIK RT kernel patches are not accepted in vanilla kernel (to which you refer as "patch-4.3"), so it is developed as separate project and provides its own patches to be applied on vanilla kernel.

I suppose RT support is developed in this repository: https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/rt/linux-rt-devel.git/
Here is a repository for vanilla kernel: https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/ 
You may try to seek any merges from RT to vanilla kernel, but I doubt that they exist.

Comment: Yes. It's correct answer -- use appropriate Git repository. Nobody uses tar-ball patches approach anymore.

Answer (score 2):

The [RT patches](https://rt.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page) are not part of the upstream, mainline kernel yet. It's a feature in development, and released as patches on top of each supported mainline kernel release. To use RT, you need to choose the RT patchset that matches the mainline kernel you want to use.

Gradually, the patches are being merged to mainline kernel. At the same time, the mainline kernel moves on, and the other out-of-tree RT patches might no longer apply without rebasing. That's why there are RT patches for each (supported) mainline kernel release.